# How to make a user friendly start of a Python program?

Tags: python, command-line, desktop, command-prompt

I have a Python program (GUI application). I can run this program from the command prompt on Windows (command line on Linux). But it can be too complicated for users. Is there an easy way to initiate a start of the program with a click (double click) on a pictogram (a small image on the desktop)?

Comment: This is only a partial solution, but if you run it [the script] with pythonw.exe it will not show a console window. It will run in the "background" so to speak. I'm not sure if pythonw.exe exists in the Linux releases though (Edit: seems like it does.)

Comment: But how I can initiate a running of a script by a click on an desktop image?

Comment: @Skurmedel: OP says that he has GUI app. He just doesn't know how to add shortcut/icon.

Comment: In Windows, you just need a shortcut file. You could create and copy, so long as you know the path for the app on the user machine. On Linux, I'm sure there's something similar, but it may well depend on the desktop (KDE, Gnome, ...). My KDE4 desktop *has* application shortcuts of a sort, but I don't know how they work - only that KDE let me put these things in various places.

Comment: I'm sorry, I read it another way.

Comment: Actually, "need" is wrong - just the idea I had in mind at the time.

Comment: Just a thought - are there any cross-platform installer creators that understand Python and its dependencies, and that could make sure the app ends up in the standard places on menus etc in each platform? I seem to remember a Python tool for doing something like this, but I don't remember the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Linux:**
I am not sure, which linux distro and desktop you use but for gnome I create such files on desktop e.. create a myapp.desktop and put in on desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=MyApp
Type=Application
Exec=python /home/anushri/display.anurag/xxx.py
TryExec=
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/gnome-qeye.png
X-GNOME-DocPath=
Terminal=false
Name[en_IN]=MyApp
GenericName[en_IN]=MyApp
Comment[en_IN]=MyApp
GenericName=MyApp
Comment=MyApp
```

**Windows:**

Right-click an open area on the desktop, point to New, and then click Shortcut, type the command line to start you program, Type a name for the shortcut

Comment: I use fedora 15, how can i create the same ?

Comment: I had tried like creating  a create.desktop file and placed the code given by u and edited the python file path and image path, now when i click on the file create.desktop nothing is happening,just refreshing and redirecting to same folder ???????

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood the question well, but if you just need a way to simulate a command line input with a simply clickable icon, just create a simple .bat file (assuming windows) on the desktop, as a new text file containing something like

> C:\[Pythonpath]\python C:\[MyPythonAppPath]\myapp.py

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file for more info.

Comment: And then change the file's icon to something else if you want.

Comment: myapp , isn't that strictly for mac ?

Answer (score 1):

Use py2exe to make an exe and just to make it more 'user friendly' use Inno set up (www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php ) along with IStools to build up an installer which would integrate the GUI with sound, widgets, other elements etc and users who do not have python etc installed in their systems can also play your GUI perfectly fine !

By the way what GUI are you using ? pygame, tk, wx, PyQt ...etc ?

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) to create an executable from my python script.  That embeds the interpreter and the source inside an EXE, that way it works just like a native executable and you don't have to have the users install python or anything complicated.